# can't switch from one panel to another panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, panel

i have a jframe class called Main that has a  method called display that uses to swap views and three panels displaypanel and buttonpanel and mainpanel in which mainpanel hold displaypanel and buttonpanel, button panel contains some buttons and displaypanel use to display swapped views means different panels, and afterward i have two jpanel classes label and New2 in which New2 a  JButton that wants to call a method(display) from the Main class, so that the New2 panel will be get removed from there(displaypanel) and  label panel will be added to the displaypanel.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: i want to switch panel which are different class, when i will click on the button on New2 panel.read the question you will understand,

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal  how to post code here..

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `Card Layout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: no i am not using a card layout....

Comment: @user3493306, I know you are not use a CardLayout. You SHOULD be using a CardLayout and it will solve your problems. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: is there any other way to the same thing.

Comment: @user3493306, There area always many ways to do anything. You can do it the way Swing was designed to be used, or you can reinvent the wheel and write the code yourself. Why do you want to do it a different way? What problems did you encounter when you trie dot use the CardLayout? If you need to ask this question then you don't understand how Swing works and should first learn how Swing works before trying to reinvent the wheel. I suggest you read the entire Swing tutorial first.

Comment: thanks for your help,but i will like to do it in my own way by my own code and also i got the answer too for the question.thanks